# Add "end" to rock, paper, scissors game and use styles on vars

Tags: javascript, css

I have finished a rock, paper and scissors exercise and implemented some DOM event, it's a very simple script but I'm almost happy with it. Well, now I'm having two issues and I don't know how to get the logic on them.

1. First question is, I would like set an end game, like max. 5 rounds then game stops / resets, but I can't think of any solution to get to it, I was thinking on using a for loop but I don't know where should I use it, maybe I shouldn't use the userScore++ and computerScore++ on the playGame function but I can't tell it for sure. Could someone please tell me how should I proceed?
2. Second question is, in my $icons constant I have set the 3 emojis, I would like to make them bigger so it would fit better on "The machine chooses.." text, but I also don't know how to, I was thinking on adding CSS styles (font-size) through JS on the DOM but I don't know where to start.

```js
// Global DOM variables
const $selectBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[data-selector]");
const $displayUserScore = document.querySelector("#user-score");
const $DisplayComputerScore = document.querySelector("#computer-score")
const $showScore = document.querySelector("h5");
const $icons = ["", "", "✂️"];

// Score vaiables
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;

// For each button of buttons...
$selectBtn.forEach(function(button){
    
    button.addEventListener("click", function() {
        let computerOption = computerRandom() // Store random computer play on var
        const userOption = button.dataset.selector; // userOption is equal to data-selector attribute
     
        // Invoke functions plays the game and shows final winner.
        playGame(userOption, computerOption);
        theWinner();
        
        // Add function with results
        function playGame(userOption, computerOption) {

            if (userOption === "rock") {
                if (computerOption === "scissors") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+$icons[2]+", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "paper") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $DisplayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+$icons[1]+", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

            if (userOption === "paper") {
                if (computerOption === "rock") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+$icons[0]+", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "scissors") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $DisplayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+$icons[2]+", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

            if (userOption === "scissors") {
                if (computerOption === "paper") {
                    userScore++;
                    $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine choses "+$icons[1]+", you BEAT him!";
                } else if (computerOption === "rock") {
                    computerScore++;
                    $DisplayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses "+$icons[0]+", you LOSE!";
                } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
                    $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
                }
            }

        }

        // Add a winners text function
        function theWinner() {
            const $theWinnerIs = document.querySelector('#result-winner');
            if (userScore >= 5) {
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "You!";
            } else if (computerScore >= 5) {
                $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "The machine!";
            }
        }

    })
    
})

// Random computer choice
function computerRandom () {
    const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
    return choices[randomNumber];
}
```

```css
body {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.btn-selector {
    font-size: 4em;
    background: rebeccapurple;
    margin: .1em;
    padding: .2em;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 20%;
    transition: 150ms;
}
.btn-selector:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}

#results {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.score {
    margin-right: 1em;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-style: italic;
}

h3 {
    color: rebeccapurple;
    font-style: italic;
}

h5 {
    margin-top: 7px;
    color: olive;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Rock, paper and scissors</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="rock"></button>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="paper"></button>
        <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="scissors">✂️</button>
        <div id="results">
        <h4>You: <span id="user-score" class="score" data-user-score>0</span></h4>
        <h4>Computer: <span id="computer-score" class="score" data-computer-score>0</span></h4>
    </div>
    <h5></h5>
        <div>
            <h3>And the winner is...</h3>
            <h3 id="result-winner"></h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define a flag as falsey (`null`, 0, `false`, etc) or just declare it **outside** of function but in scope:

**Figure I**

```js
let flag = false;

function play(event) {//...
```

On each round check to see if the sum of both scores is greater than 4. If it is, wrap up the game:

**Figure II**

```js
// Somewhere at the end of event handler play(e)
if ((+IO.a.value + (+IO.b.value)) > 4) {
  flag = true;
  let WL = +IO.a.value > +IO.b.value ? 'win' : 'lose';
  IO.outcome.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p>${IO.a.value} out of 5, you ${WL} the game.</p>`);
  IO.outcome.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p>Click "Rock", "Paper", or "Scissors" button to play another 5 rounds.</p>`);
}
```

Make sure the flag is reset and clear out the old scores:

**Figure III**

```js
// Somewhere at the beginning of event handler play(e)
if (flag) {
  [...IO.ab].forEach(AB => AB.value = '');
  flag = false;
}
```

The procedure above is implemented in the game below. It only uses a single event handler for all three buttons (see [events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events) and [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation)). The majority of the DOM is comprised of a `<form>` and [form controls](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Content_categories#form-associated_content) and the terse syntax is provided by the [HTMLFormElement](https://javascript.info/form-elements) and the [HTMLFormControlsCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection) interfaces. It is very responsive, open in Full page mode. If your layout is simple try assigning `font-size` with [`vmin`](http://thenewcode.com/1137/MinMaxing-Understanding-vMin-and-vMax-in-CSS) units at the root (`:root` or `html`). Any lengths defined with [`rem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Values_and_units) units will automatically resize relative to the default `font-size` at root:

**Figure IV**

```css
html {
  font: 500 3vmin/1.2 'Segoe UI';
}
```

### Example

```js
const rps = ["", "", "✂️"];
const cbn = ["", "", ""];
let result, flag = false;

const RPS = document.forms.roshambo;

RPS.onclick = play;

function play(e) {
  const IO = this.elements;
  const clk = e.target;
  let sel, VS;

  if (clk.matches('#A .btn')) {
    if (flag) {
      [...IO.ab].forEach(AB => AB.value = '');
      flag = false;
    }
    sel = +clk.value;
    VS = 3 * Math.random() << 0;
    IO.outcome.textContent = '';
    result = sel === VS ? ["You tied this round", null] :
      sel === VS + 1 || sel === 0 && VS === 2 ? ["You win this round!", "a"] : ["You lose this round", "b"];
    IO.outcome.textContent = result[0];
    if (result[1]) {
      IO[result[1]].value = +IO[result[1]].value + 1;
    }
    IO.active.textContent = rps[VS];
    if ((+IO.a.value + (+IO.b.value)) > 4) {
      flag = true;
      let WL = +IO.a.value > +IO.b.value ? 'win' : 'lose';
      IO.outcome.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p>${IO.a.value} out of 5, you ${WL} the game.</p>`);
      IO.outcome.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', `<p>Click "Rock", "Paper", or "Scissors" button to play another 5 rounds.</p>`);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  font: 300 3vmin/1.2 'Segoe UI';
}

#rashambo {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin: 10% auto;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.btn {
  margin: 0.75rem;
  padding: 1.2rem;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20%;
  outline: 0;
  font-size: 4rem;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 150ms;
}

#A .btn:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

.score {
  font-size: 2.25rem;
  color: rebeccapurple;
}

.outcome {
  min-height:3rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  line-height: 1.75;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: olive;
}

output {
  font-family: Consolas;
  font-size: 3rem;
  line-height: 1;
  vertical-align: text-top;
  color: goldenrod;
}

#active {
  color: olive;
  background: olive;
}

#B .btn.inactive {
  color: transparent;
  background: transparent;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Roshambo! Rock, Paper, and Scissors</title>

</head>

<body>
  <form id='roshambo'>
    <fieldset id='A' class="row">
      <button name='btn' class="btn" type="button" value="0"></button>
      <button name='btn' class="btn" type="button" value="1"></button>
      <button name='btn' class="btn" type="button" value="2">✂️</button>
      <label class="score"><b>A</b> (YOU): <output id='a' name="ab">0</output></label>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='outcome' class='outcome'>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset id='B' class="row">
      <button name='btn' class="btn inactive" type="button"></button>
      <button id='active' name='btn' class="btn" type="button">▋▉</button>
      <button name='btn' class="btn inactive" type="button">✂️</button>
      <label class="score"><b>B</b> (CPU): <output id='b' name="ab">0</output></label>
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ey, thank you very much and nice touch, tho it's a little hard for me since I'm missing parts (I am still a newbie on JS) but I will read it as much as I can to learn from it :)

Comment: No problem, I forgot to mention that I narrowed down the algorithm for determining if player wins or loses down to a single line (that's the whole `playGame()` function), see the `result` variable in example.

Answer (score 0):

### To have a count of the scores and reset the game

At every click, check whether either the user score or the computer score has reached 5 and call `theWinner()` function

```js
button.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // rest of the code

    if (userScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
        theWinner();
        userScore = 0;
        computerScore = 0;
        $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
        $DisplayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
    }
}
```

Modify your `theWinner()` function.

```js
function theWinner() {
    const $theWinnerIs = document.querySelector('#result-winner');
    if (userScore > computerScore) {
        $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "You!";
    } else if (userScore < computerScore) {
        $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "The machine!";
    } else {
        $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "Draw!";
    }
}
```

---

### To change the size of the icon:

For this, you have to modify the `innerHTML` of every `$showScore` to this:

```js
$showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses " + "<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
```

Add this CSS to it: set the display to `inline-block` as it's `inline` by default and scale it to the desired size. `transform` property doesn't work on `inline` elements.

```css
.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: scale(2);
}
```

---

### Complete code:

```js
// Global DOM variables
const $selectBtn = document.querySelectorAll("[data-selector]");
const $displayUserScore = document.querySelector("#user-score");
const $DisplayComputerScore = document.querySelector("#computer-score")
const $showScore = document.querySelector("h5");
const $icons = ["", "", "✂️"];

// Score vaiables
const choices = ["rock", "paper", "scissors"];
let userScore = 0;
let computerScore = 0;


// For each button of buttons...
$selectBtn.forEach(function(button) {

  button.addEventListener("click", function() {

    let computerOption = computerRandom() // Store random computer play on var
    const userOption = button.dataset.selector; // userOption is equal to data-selector attribute

    // Invoke functions plays the game and shows final winner.
    playGame(userOption, computerOption);

    // Add function with results
    function playGame(userOption, computerOption) {

      if (userOption === "rock") {
        if (computerOption === "scissors") {
          userScore++;
          $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
          $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses " + "<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
        } else if (computerOption === "paper") {
          computerScore++;
          $DisplayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
          $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses " + "<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[1] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
        } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
          $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
        }
      }

      if (userOption === "paper") {
        if (computerOption === "rock") {
          userScore++;
          $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
          $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses " + "<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[0] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
        } else if (computerOption === "scissors") {
          computerScore++;
          $DisplayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
          $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses " + "<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[2] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
        } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
          $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
        }
      }

      if (userOption === "scissors") {
        if (computerOption === "paper") {
          userScore++;
          $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
          $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine choses " + "<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[1] + "</span>" + ", you BEAT him!";
        } else if (computerOption === "rock") {
          computerScore++;
          $DisplayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
          $showScore.innerHTML = "The machine chooses " + "<span class=\"icon\">" + $icons[0] + "</span>" + ", you LOSE!";
        } else if (userOption === computerOption) {
          $showScore.innerHTML = "Draw!";
        }
      }

    }

    // Add a winners text function
    function theWinner() {
      const $theWinnerIs = document.querySelector('#result-winner');
      if (userScore > computerScore) {
        $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "You!";
      } else if (userScore < computerScore) {
        $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "The machine!";
      } else {
        $theWinnerIs.innerHTML = "Draw!";
      }
    }

    if (userScore === 5 || computerScore === 5) {
      theWinner();
      userScore = 0;
      computerScore = 0;
      $displayUserScore.innerHTML = userScore;
      $DisplayComputerScore.innerHTML = computerScore;
    }
  })
})

// Random computer choice
function computerRandom() {
  const randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * choices.length);
  return choices[randomNumber];
}
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 10%;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: scale(2);
}

.btn-selector {
  font-size: 4em;
  background: rebeccapurple;
  margin: 0.1em;
  padding: 0.2em;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 20%;
  transition: 150ms;
}

.btn-selector:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

#results {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.score {
  margin-right: 1em;
  font-size: 11px;
  font-style: italic;
}

h3 {
  color: rebeccapurple;
  font-style: italic;
}

h5 {
  margin-top: 7px;
  color: olive;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="rock"></button>
  <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="paper"></button>
  <button class="btn-selector" data-selector="scissors">✂️</button>
  <div id="results">
    <h4>You: <span id="user-score" class="score" data-user-score>0</span></h4>
    <h4>Computer: <span id="computer-score" class="score" data-computer-score>0</span></h4>
  </div>
  <h5></h5>
  <div>
    <h3>And the winner is...</h3>
    <h3 id="result-winner"></h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Link to codepen: https://codepen.io/geekyquentin/pen/WNMaxMd

Comment: Sorry, I am new here, I answered to what you did write to me but I don't know if is better to comment it. Noe enough characters anyway,